# Axios interceptors и вывод сообщения об асинхронной загрузке

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Использую vue.js и axios для отправки запросов к API. Есть необходимость глобально настроить отображение заглушки на весь экран, если запрос выполняется долго

- Отправляем запрос. Если он длится более 500мс, то отображаем заглушку на весь экран
- Если ошибка запроса - выводим сообщение об ошибке
- В случае успешного запроса ничего не выводим

Выяснилось, что axios [можно](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) настроить глобально, чтобы отлавливать действия до момента отправки запроса, после получения ответа, а также ловить ошибки. В общем виде это выглядит так

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    // Do something before request is sent
    return config;
  }, (error) => {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });

// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  }, (error) => {
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

Для вывода сообщений пользователю использую библиотеку [f3oall/awesome-notifications](https://github.com/f3oall/awesome-notifications) (есть [отдельный билд для vue](https://github.com/f3oall/vue-awesome-notifications)). В документации указано, что заглушка на весь экран выводится вот так

```
asyncBlock(promise, onResolve, onReject, html)
```

Также можно отдельно завершать успехом или ошибкой

```
notifier.asyncBlock(Promise.resolve("all done")) // won't show anything after promise resolved
notifier.asyncBlock(Promise.reject("some error")) // will show a new alert toast with message "some error"
```

Однако как можно это использовать вместе с `axios.interceptors` не понимаю. Ведь у меня два `interceptors`. И как в первом, например, начать `asyncBlock`, а во втором закончить?

Как быть? Может есть другие варианты?